# How to apply style on ::after pseudo element when hovering ::before pseudo (not the host element)?

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-element

There are similar questions out there, but apparently the same like this I didn't found. So question is:

*How to apply some styling on ::after pseudo element when hovering ::before pseudo (not the host element)?*

Code example:

```css
.contact {
  position: relative;
}

.contact::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -10px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

.contact::after {
  content: 'Preferred contact';
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -15px;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);

  display: none;
}

.contact:hover::after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <span class="contact">skype_hello85</span>
```

So when hovering element (span) itself - everything is fine. But I want to ::after would be shown only when ::before is hovering, not the host element itself.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: short answer: you cannot. But if you can change the html you can do it

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I know about that. I just was interesting in if it is possible to make it without extra HTML noise.

Comment: Not working. `::after` or `::before` has no hover statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply styles to elements that lay inside the first selector DOM level.

For example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    ::before
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    ::after
</div>
```

`wrapper` class contain here **p** tag and two pseudo-elements (*::before* and *::after*) and they all lay in one DOM level and styling the *::before* elements devepeding on *::after* element is impossible. The only way is to apply styles to `wrapper` CSS class or use JS.

More information you can get [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance#Inheritance).